# Can't delete a Sanity project

Tags: sanity

I recently set up a new Sanity project via the CLI, but accidentally used the wrong file path. Now I'm unable to delete the project from within Sanity via Project > Settings > Delete Project. I keep getting a vague error "Could not delete project." Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, my problem ended up being a matter of org permissions. I was set to `developer` and not `administrator` — changing that fixed my issue.

If anyone from Sanity sees this, although it might seem obvious in hindsight, I'd maybe suggest updating the error message to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

simply go to this address and delate https://www.sanity.io/manage/personal/projects

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).